# Clear the navigation history of WebView in WinRT Windows Store App C#

Tags: c#, webview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

### Scenario

I am creating a simple embedded "browser" for my app, which opens in a `Popup`, when the user clicks on a button with a hyperlink designed to open "in-app".

The popup is opened, and the (simply-named) `WebView` is navigated to the URL specified in the hyperlink.

There are the typical Back, Forward and Refresh/Stop buttons that are enabled/disabled accordingly.

---

### Current Situation

I have wired up the necessary events for `NavigationStarted`, `NavigationCompleted` and others for Falied, Loaded etc. etc.

These are performed along with some "naughty" ViewModel wiring when the `UserControl` is loaded *TL;DR - there is no way I can find to keep to MVVM practice with WebViews, what a PITA!*:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is IWebViewUserControlViewModel)
    {
        this.WebView.ContentLoading += OnWebViewContentLoading;
        this.WebView.DOMContentLoaded += OnWebViewDomContentLoaded;
        this.WebView.NavigationStarting += OnWebViewNavigationStarting;
        this.WebView.NavigationCompleted += OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
        this.WebView.UnviewableContentIdentified += OnWebViewUnviewableContentIdentified;
        this.WebView.NavigationFailed += OnWebViewNavigationFailed;

        this.viewModel = DataContext as IWebViewUserControlViewModel;
        NavigateToUrl(this.viewModel?.Url);
    }
}
```

This is so that I navigate to the URL when the `UserControl` is loaded, and can evaluate the button states as the user navigates around using the events above.

The `NavigateToUrl()` method just contains a `try`/`catch` block to counteract any errors forming the `Uri` etc.:

```
private void NavigateToUrl(string url)
{
    try 
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        this.WebView.Navigate(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.WebView.NavigateToString($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}")
    }
}
```

---

### Back/Forward UX

In particular the Back and Forward buttons are disabled/enabled when navigation to a page is started/completed respectively.

I evaluate their `IsEnabled` states like so:

```
btnBackButton.IsEnabled = this.WebView.CanGoBack;
btnForwardButton.IsEnabled = this.WebView.CanGoForward;
```

This works fine throughout the entire time that the user is browsing.

---

### The Issue

Should the user close the popup, and re-open it via the same or a different link, the correct URL is navigated to - all good.

The issue is, that their previous browsing session was never cleared from the `MyWebView`, and thus the `btnBackButton` (not the forward, as this the latest navigation in the history stack) is now enabled again - allowing them to traverse their previously visited pages.

I don't want this behaviour.

I would like it to appear that their session is a "new", fresh one - without the Back button enabled - as if it had just been opened.

---

### What I have already tried...

I am unable to manually set the `MyWebView.CanGoBack`/`MyWebView.CanGoForward` properties to false when the popup is (re)opened.

They are `get`-only properties, so this is not possible.

---

I have tried re-initializing the `WebView` control when the containing `UserControl` is `Loaded` (in the same `OnLoaded` delegate as above):

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is IWebViewUserControlViewModel)
    {
        // Re-initialize the WebView
        this.WebView = new WebView();

        // Detect when the new control has loaded, and then wire up events/navigate as normal
        this.WebView.Loaded += (sender, e) => 
        {           
            this.WebView.ContentLoading += OnWebViewContentLoading;
            this.WebView.DOMContentLoaded += OnWebViewDomContentLoaded;
            this.WebView.NavigationStarting += OnWebViewNavigationStarting;
            this.WebView.NavigationCompleted += OnWebViewNavigationCompleted;
            this.WebView.UnviewableContentIdentified += OnWebViewUnviewableContentIdentified;
            this.WebView.NavigationFailed += OnWebViewNavigationFailed;

            this.viewModel = DataContext as IWebViewUserControlViewModel;
            NavigateToUrl(this.viewModel?.Url);
        }
    }
}
```

In the hope that this might work - but the `Loaded` delegate of the `WebView` is never fired.

In the UI, the `WebView` just doesn't appear.

---

### Help!?

Is there any way for me to clear the navigation history for the `WebView` control, so it appears that the browsing session is a "new" one?

Your help is appreciated, as always. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is Windows 8.1, actually there is no programmatic way to clear the webview cache according to what @Matt said in [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/10/18/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview/#AN7)(part 7).

And if it is a UWP app, please refer to [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.cleartemporarywebdataasync.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Neal for your suggestion. Upvoted. App is a Windows 8.1 Store App. I've had a quick look at the link you provided and I'll see if there is a way I can programmatically perform this clearing of the History, Cache, Cookies etc. Just for future reference, as links can go bad: is it possible you could include the quote in your answer in case it does; then any future visitors to this question will be able to see the important part in case the inevitable happens. Obviously, including the link for reference is still advised. Thanks again :)